# Why is the value of n not updating?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, return-value

The value of n is staying 1 throughout the loop. It is stopping after the input is entered 0 (as required), but every time I print the value of n, it is staying 1. I would appreciate any explanation or solution for this.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getInteger() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    return n;
}
int main(void) {
    int n;
    while (n = getInteger() != 0) {
        printf("Entered value is: %d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The operator `!=` has higher precedence than `=`. Have a look at this [blog](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-precedence-and-associativity-in-c/).

Not using the operator correctly caused the unwanted  logical error in your case, which can be solved with the correct use of parenthesis as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getInteger() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    return n;
}
int main(void) {
    int n;
    while ( (n = getInteger()) != 0) {
        printf("Entered value is: %d\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), which defines what operators bind more strongly when there is a lack of parentheses, i.e. does `a = b != c` result in `(a = b) != c` or `a = (b != c)`? It results in the later because `!=` binds more than `=`.

To resolve the issue you need to explicitly wrap parentheses around the assignment:

```c
while ((n = getInteger()) != 0)
```